# How to setup R extension in NetLogo 6.0 - Windows

Tags: r, netlogo

Since I probably won't be the only one who encounters this, I am providing a solution.

I have installed NetLogo 6.0 x64 in Win10.  I have R installed with the rJava package located in D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rJava.

In NetLogo 6, I put

```
extensions [r]
```

in the Code tab, but it gave an error message:

```
Cannot locate rJava/JRI.  Please check the location of your rJava installation and add a user.properties file in the r extension directory.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened the extension folder in NetLogo C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0\app\extensions\r) and modified the user.properties file thus:

```
 r.home=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2
 jri.home.paths=D:\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rJava\jri\
```

That made the error message go away (after restarting NetLogo 6.0).